# Lateral limits of odd and even functions

Tags: calculus, limits

So this question asks:

- $f$ is an even function and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L \in \mathbb{R} \neq 0$, what can we say about $\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f(x)$?

and:

- $f$ is an odd function and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L \in \mathbb{R} \neq 0$, what can we say about $\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f(x)$?

So what came in my mind:

If the global limit exists, then the lateral limit to the left also exists, and there's nothing to worry about the functions being odd or even. What I don't understand is why the exercise asks specifically in the case of and odd function, an even function, and both with limit diferente than $0$. Is there a problem in the limit being equal to $0$? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure those $a$s are not supposed to be $0$s?

Comment: @Goos pretty sure, here in my paper they're $a$s. Any idea in case of $0$s?

Comment: OK, I just don't get how odd or even has anything to do with that limit when $a \ne 0$.

Comment: @goos me too. Any idea in case of $a = 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of $a = 0$,
notice that
$\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x)$
is equivalent to $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(-x)$.
Therefore,

- If $f$ is even,
  $$
  L = \lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x)
  = \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(-x)
  = \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = L.
  $$
- If $f$ is odd,
  $$
  L = \lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x)
  = \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(-x)
  = \lim_{x \to 0^+} -f(x) = -L.
  $$

In the odd case, we conclude $L = 0$.
In the even case, $L$ could be anything.

Notice that $f(0)$ itself doesn't have to be anything in particular, nor do we need $L = f(0)$ or anything like that.  This is because we did not require $f$ to be continuous at $0$.

Comment: but wait, if the global limit exists, shouldn't the limit to the left be equal to the limit to the right?

Comment: @MarterJs Shoot!  You are right, I misread your question as the limit from the positive side exists.

Comment: @MarterJs I updated my answer.

Comment: But if the global limit exists, shouldn't the limit in both sides be the same, independent of the function being odd or even? I also don't understand when $L = \lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x)
= \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(-x)
= \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = L.
 
$ Works only for $a=0$

Comment: @MarterJs My entire answer is just for the case $a = 0$.  And think about it like a picture.  For the limit to be the same for an odd function from both sides, clearly you will need the limit to be zero.  But for an even function, you don't have any trouble.

Comment: but my question says that the limit $L$ is never equal to $0$

Comment: @MarterJs Then no such odd function exists.